# GGPLOT: heatmap with missing values (with grid)

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

How to make ggplot to fill missing categories ("c" in week 2 and "a" in week 3) on a heatmap without making new table with cells containing 0?

```
test <- data.frame(week = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 2), rep(3,2)),
                   category = c(letters[1:3], letters [1:2], letters[2:3]),
                   value = runif(7, 0, 5))

test
  week category    value
1    1        a 3.548721
2    1        b 2.589749
3    1        c 2.237209
4    2        a 3.584663
5    2        b 1.620177
6    3        b 3.028124
7    3        c 2.223177

ggplot(test, aes(week, category, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(color = "black")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to fake it by expanding the plot area and setting the panel background and grid lines to black.

Edit: Original output did not show the x-axis (took some digging to figure out why) since I used `scale_x_discrete` instead of `scale_x_continuous`. Because the x-axis or "week" is a continuous variable here, the breaks argument needs to be manually named. Alternatively, you can change week to a categorical and use `scale_x_discrete`.

```
ggplot(test, aes(week, category, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(color = "black") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), breaks = unique(test$week)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
    panel.grid = element_line(color = "black"))
```

[image]